# Want to read more about medical intellectual property and the TPP

Tags: reference-request, international-trade, intellectual-property

I'm trying to find information about the current state of medical IP protection in countries willing to sign the TPP and the change they will go trough and maybe some impact analysis.

I was hoping maybe i would catch someone currently swimming in this stuff right now and willing to share knowledge or links to valid informaiton